# Android Navigation View set menu programmatically

Tags: android, view, menu, navigation

In my app I want to pass certain menu depending of some condition.

This is the layout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_free"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/Color_White"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer_1"
        />
```

All I want to do is to change dynamically the @menu/activity_main_drawer_1 depending of some condition.

How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: you want to change the whole menu or just want to change menuItem of this menu..?

Comment: i want to change the whole menu

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `inflateMenu` on your `NavigationView`.

For example:

```
navigationView.getMenu().clear();
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_view);
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#inflateMenu(int)) for more information.

Comment: Is it necessary to call  `navigationView.getMenu().clear()`? Thanks!

Comment: otherwise it retains previous items and appends new menu

Answer (score 24):

`navigationView.getMenu().clear();
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_menu);`

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
val menu = navigationView.menu
val submenu = menu.addSubMenu("New set")

submenu.add("Item1")
submenu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.item1)
submenu.add("Item2")
submenu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.item2)
submenu.add("Item3")
submenu.getItem(2).setIcon(R.drawable.item3)
navigationView.invalidate()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

```
Create Generic class Implements Menu iterface then add menu item 
NavigationView  nd=(NavigationView )findViewById(R.id.nav_view_free);

Menu mn=new Menu();

mn.add("email");

mn.add("email");

mn.add("email");

mn.add("email");

nd(mn);
```

Comment: This answer won't work. You can't instantiate a menu (using constructor). You can't set a menu on the NavigationView.